# Por qué me genera resultado null en String y en int 0.0 al ejecutar un código Java, pero me compila normal?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package laboratorio6;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaracion de variables
        String nombre[];
        String nacionalidad[];
        double tiempo[];
        int totalAtletas;
        double may=0;
        String nombremin = null;
        String nacionalidadmin = null;
        String nacionalidadpais;
        String nombreatletapais;
        double sumTiempo=0;
        double tiempoPromedio;
        //Menu
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "                           Competencia \n" +
        "1. Registrar Atleta \n" + "2. Datos del campeon \n" + "3. Atletas por pais \n" +
        "4. Tiempo promedio de todos los atletas \n" + "5. Salir");
        totalAtletas=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de Atletas "));
        nombre=new String[totalAtletas];
        nacionalidad=new String[totalAtletas];
        tiempo=new double[totalAtletas];
        //Registrar atletas
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1. Registrar Atleta");
        for(int i=0; i<totalAtletas; i++){
            nombre[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre del Atleta:  ");
            nacionalidad[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la nacionalidad del Atleta:  ");
            tiempo[i]=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el tiempo en minutos del Atleta: "));
            sumTiempo=sumTiempo+tiempo[i];
        }
        //Datos campeon
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2. Datos del campeon");
        for (int i=0; i<totalAtletas; i++){
            if (tiempo[i]<may){
                may=tiempo[i];
                nombremin=nombre[i];
                nacionalidadmin=nacionalidad[i];
            }
        }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre del atleta  campeon es " + nombremin   + " de nacionalidad "
                + nacionalidadmin + " cuyo tiempo fue " + may);
        //Atletas por pais
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "3. Atletas por pais");
        nacionalidadpais=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la nacionalidad para mostrar los atletas de ese pais:  ");      
        for (int i=0; i<totalAtletas; i++){
            if (nacionalidadpais == null ? nacionalidad[i] == null : nacionalidadpais.equals(nacionalidad[i])){
                nombreatletapais=nombre[i];
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de un atleta de nacionalidad " + nacionalidadpais + " es "
                + nombreatletapais);
            }
        }
        //Promedio del tiempo de los atletas
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "4. Tiempo promedio de todos los atletas");
        tiempoPromedio=sumTiempo/totalAtletas;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El tiempo promedio de los atletas fue " + tiempoPromedio);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "5. Salir");
    }

}
```

Comment: Inicializa 'may' con un valor muy alto, ya que estas sacando el maximo en vez de minimo.

`max - 99999;
min - 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es lógico , Le muestra `null` y `0` por qué no entra nunca al `if (tiempo[i]<may){` *(a menos que ingrese tiempos negativos)* por lo cuál los valores de las variables no cambian. Sí quiere validar el menor tiempo podría declarar la variable `may` de la siguiente forma .

```
 double may=Double.MAX_VALUE;
```